# Loading Gridview is choppy

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to load a gridview with cards that hold product information.

I'm not sure if this is the best way of handling this sort of data loading.

First i'm setting my adapter:

`cardView.setAdapter(new productCardAdapter(getActivity(),products));`

Products is a object that holds a product object, inside the product object has values like image,name,price, etc..

in my `public class productCardAdapter extends BaseAdapter`

I set the products

`this.products = products;`

then in the

`public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {`

I am setting the values based off the index `i`

```
if(view == null){

    // CREATE NEW
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_card,null);

    // GET CURRENT PRODUCT
    Products.Product product = products.products.get(i);

    // CREATE WIDGETS
    TextView cardTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
    ImageView cardImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgProductImage);
    CardView card = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.tmpCard);
    TextView cardSKU = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtProductSKU);
    TextView cardPrice = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtProductPrice);

    // GET IMAGE
    if (product.picture.length() > 0) {

        // PUT IMAGE
        cardImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(functions.getLocalPicturePath(product.picture)));

    }else{

        // GENERATE GRADIENT
        card.setBackground(colors.generateGradient());

    }


    // SET VALUES
    cardTitle.setText(product.name);
    cardSKU.setText(product.sku);

    cardPrice.setText("$"+product.price);

    // CHECK FOR SALE PRICE
    if(product.salePrice > 0){
        cardPrice.setText("$"+product.salePrice);
    }

}

return view;
```

when loading it makes a choppy transition that lasts close to 1 second.

Is there ways I can improve on this?

Comment: that `cardImage.setImageBitmap` is the time consuming one. Consider a lazy-loading library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [enable `StrictMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html). It will then yell at you that you are doing disk I/O on the main application thread. It won't yell at you that you are doing an expensive bitmap-decoding operation on the main application thread, though that's a problem too.

Then, as njzk2 suggests, use one of [the vast array of image-loading libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), to load your image asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Google's sample code https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html is setting a **bad example** !

To fix that sample code, instead of :

```
imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
```

You'll want to use a library, I used Glide, to load the image in a thread. Like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CircleImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        // not recycled
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_image, parent, false);
        imageView = (CircleImageView) view;
    } else {
        // recycled
        imageView = (CircleImageView) convertView;
    }

    Glide
            .with(parent.getContext())
            .load(mThumbIds[position])
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)//REQUIRED
            .dontAnimate()//REQUIRED
            .into(imageView);

    //imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return imageView;
}
```

Get CircleImageView here: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView
Get Glide here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

By the way, the XML for my `R.layout.item_image` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image_avatar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
```